# Getting Error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: livewire is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, promise, livewire-3

I am trying to call wire:click="deleteImage(1)" through jquery -

```
livewire.emit('deleteImage', 1);
```

but getting an error - **Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: livewire is not defined**

Comment: My updated code - 
`@this.deleteImage(1);`
It’s working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that livewire has been initialized.
Also *emit* is a 2.0 method to dispatch events, it can't be used directly to call methods.

Here a simplified working example:

```php
<?php
//class App\Livewire\JQry

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class JQry extends Component
{
    public $test = 1;


    public function add()
    {
        $this->test++;
    }
}
```

```blade
{{-- resources/views/livewire/j-qry.blade.php --}}

<div>

    <button id="but1">
        [Add 1]
    </button>

    <br>

    {{ $test }}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    document.addEventListener("livewire:init", () => {

            $("#but1").on ("click", () => {

                // add() is an example method from the Livewire class - in your case you will call deleteImage(1)
                window.Livewire.getByName("j-qry")[0].add();

                // @this.add(); ---> if the script is set in the template we can use this shorthand format

            });
    });

</script>

</div>
```

Comment: I have initialise livewire scripts just before ending the body tag. And I have changed my code as - 
`document.addEventListener('livewire:init', () => {
 $("#button_id").on ("click", () => {
  alert(‘test’);
        });
});`
Now I didn’t get any error, but script is not working..nothing happens when click on the button.

Comment: It seems that *livewire:init* is not detected. You are using Livewire 3.x right? There is at least  a Livewire component in the page?

Comment: Yes, i am using livewire 3.4

Comment: Check if Livewire scripts are loaded (e.g. using *view source* from your browser). With the default configuration you must include at leasr one component to allow the scripts loading

Comment: I have checked livewire scripts are loaded and there is component too.

Comment: I have changed my code as - 
`@this.deleteImage(1);`
Its's working now.. Thanks @pippo